# select statement in the query is causing to not compile

Tags: sql-server-2008

this simple code is causing the sp to not compile with all sorts of errors : all i am trying to do is check this table at the customer site if its empty then we don't display the app.

```
if (select count(*) from oen.dbd_c_modules) > 0 begin

insert into [OEN].[DBD_C_MODULES]([MODULE_ID], [DESCRIPTION], ACTIVE)
VALUES(11,'Medications',1)


end

go
```

errors:
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure DBD_GET_MEDICINE, Line 24
Incorrect syntax near 'end'.
Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 15
Must declare the scalar variable "@DATEFROM".
Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 16
Must declare the scalar variable "@DATEFROM".
Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 39
Must declare the scalar variable "@FACILITYKEY".
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 52
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AND'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 56
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AND'.

code: is here: http://www.mediafire.com/?16qr8xaszq025b6

Comment: What flavour of SQL are you using?

Comment: Can you show all of the code for the SP?

Comment: Have you declared the variables it's complaining about?

Comment: @Borodin - The error messages look like SQL server messages, although which specific release is unknown. The syntax is also consistent with SQL Server.

Comment: its sql server 2008 r2 here is the code.

Comment: IF
 EXISTS(select * from [OEN].[DBD_C_MODULES]) 
BEGIN
 
IF NOT EXISTS(select 1 from [OEN].[DBD_C_MODULES] WHERE MODULE_ID = 11 ) 
INSERT INTO [OEN].[DBD_C_MODULES]([MODULE_ID], [DESCRIPTION], ACTIVE) VALUES(11,'Medications',1)
IF NOT EXISTS(select 1 from [OEN].[DBD_C_MODULES] WHERE MODULE_ID = 15 ) 
INSERT INTO [OEN].[DBD_C_MODULES]([MODULE_ID], [DESCRIPTION], ACTIVE) VALUES(15,'Orders',1) 
END

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need if(...):

```
INSERT INTO [OEN].[DBD_C_MODULES]([MODULE_ID], [DESCRIPTION], ACTIVE)
VALUES(11,'Medications',1)
WHERE (select count(*) from oen.dbd_c_modules) > 0
  ;
```

[personally, I frown upon the uncorrelated subquery, but that is another matter]

EDIT:
Alternative formulation:

```
INSERT INTO [OEN].[DBD_C_MODULES]([MODULE_ID], [DESCRIPTION], ACTIVE)
VALUES(11,'Medications',1)
WHERE NOT EXISTS (select * from oen.dbd_c_modules)
  ;
```

Comment: I get errors on that  Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure DBD_GET_MEDICINE, Line 16
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure DBD_GET_MEDICINE, Line 16
Incorrect syntax near '>'.

Answer (score 2):

I think we need to see all the code - the errors list variables that are not within the snippet and the `GO` keyword is not a part of TSQL syntax for a stored procedure, it's an end of batch marker for SSMS. (That `GO` keyword may be causing your problems if it is really there)

Looking at the full code you posted, you have placed GO keywords in your stored procedure, that is not valid TSQL Syntax, that 'ends' the batch you are sending to the server, so cuts the stored procedure in half. The errors then come from it complaining about the GO keyword, then attempting to run the second batch you are submitting (the second half of the procedure) at which point it doesn't know what the variables are that you have declared, so throws errors on those for good measure.

Just remove the 'GO' within your code and try compile it again.